# Distance Transform In Image?

Tags: distance, image-processing

I understand how to compute Distance Transform for [BW image](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwdist.html)
In BW image we can calculate the distance of the pixel with non zero pixel value using Eucledian Distance.

But I dont undertand how to calculate it for [GrayScale](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graydist.html) and RGB (Colour) Image??
And what is purpose by calculating the DT?? What we can use with information of DT??

Answer (score 1):

One typical application of the distance transform in computer vision is pattern matching, that is, being able to identify and locate an object in an image. An object is described by a set of primitives, typically edges. The distance transform is then employed to find the distance between corresponding edges.

When a new image is presented, pixels are marked as 0 or 1 depending on whether a feature is present or not. Then the distance transform is employed search of a position in the image where the distance of image features to the model features is small enough.

There many applications of this idea. See for example [here](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/login.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5206777&url=http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=5206777)